# Issue with filtering data.table for dates - works with fixed date but not with variable

Tags: r, date, data.table

I want to filter a data.table for dates - given start- and end-dates, I want to have all the rows which include a given date.

Now my problem: It works when I use a fixed date, but it returns an empty table when I want to store the date in an external variable. Any hints?

```
dt = data.table(begin=as.Date('2014-01-01'):as.Date('2014-01-10'),
                end=as.Date('2014-01-01'):as.Date('2014-01-10')+c(1,1,1,2:8),
                x=c('A','B','C','D','E','J','J','J','J','J'))
dt[,`:=`(begin_idate=as.IDate(begin, origin='1970-1-1'),
         end_idate=as.IDate(end, origin= '1970-1-1'))]
dt[as.Date('2014-01-09')>begin_idate  & as.Date('2014-01-09')<=end_idate ] # works
x=as.Date('2014-01-09')
dt[x>begin_idate  & x<=end_idate ] #doesnt' work - empty data.table
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to the fact, that one of the columns of your `data.table` is named `x`. As `data.table` evaluates its first argument (the one you are using) it looks for `x` as column reference first. So in fact `x>begin_idate` is interpreted as

```
dt$x > dt$begin_idate
```

Which throws an error.

To fix this use a name that is not already a column name of `dt`. For example

```
xx = as.Date('2014-01-09')
dt[xx>begin_idate  & xx<=end_idate ]
```

Result:

```
> dt[xx>begin_idate  & xx<=end_idate ]
   begin   end x begin_idate  end_idate
1: 16076 16080 J  2014-01-06 2014-01-10
2: 16077 16082 J  2014-01-07 2014-01-12
3: 16078 16084 J  2014-01-08 2014-01-14
```

In fact the results are equal:

```
all.equal(dt[as.Date('2014-01-09')>begin_idate  & as.Date('2014-01-09')<=end_idate ],
          dt[xx>begin_idate  & xx<=end_idate ]) # TRUE
```